Aligning labels above the bars
I am trying to create a interaction bar graph where means are to be shown above the bars.
This is the required output. I tried but in vain. Any help?

library(ggplot2)

# Create data frame
data <- data.frame(
  ModeOfExpression = rep(c("Pour (less deliberate)", "Type (more deliberate)"), each = 2),
  Group = rep(c("In-group cue present", "Out-group cue present"), 2),
  Candies = c(2.24, 3.81, 2.59, 2.61)
)

# Create bar plot
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = ModeOfExpression, y = Candies, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(), colour = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%.2f", Candies), 
                y = Candies),   # Avoid labeling zero values
            position = position_dodge(), vjust = -0.5) +
  labs(title = "Number of Candies Taken by Mode of Expression",
       y = "Number of candies taken (Log + 1)",
       x = "") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "white")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1.5))

# Print the plot
print(p)


You can use the width params of both geom_bar() and the of the position_dodge() calls within geom_bar() and geom_text() to get what you want.  Below is an example where I set the width param of geom_bar() to 0.6, and the within-position_dodge width param to 0.8 for both geom_bar() and `geom_text(). You should see something like this

Note: I made two smaller changes as well:
1 - remove the hjust in your theme(..., plot_title = ...)
2 - use vjust = -1 in the geom_text() call.
Full code here:
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(
  ModeOfExpression = rep(c("Pour (less deliberate)", "Type (more deliberate)"), each = 2),
  Group = rep(c("In-group cue present", "Out-group cue present"), 2),
  Candies = c(2.24, 3.81, 2.59, 2.61)
)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = ModeOfExpression, y = Candies, fill = Group)) +
  geom_bar(width=.6,stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(.8), colour = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%.2f", Candies), 
                y = Candies),   # Avoid labeling zero values
            position = position_dodge(width = .8), vjust=-1) +
  labs(title = "Number of Candies Taken by Mode of Expression",
       y = "Number of candies taken (Log + 1)",
       x = "") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "white")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text())

p


Is there any possibility to give a small gap between ingroup and outgroup bars?
